# Why does this keyListener not work?

Tags: java, events, applet

```
public class game extends Applet implements KeyListener {
int movex = 10;
int movey = 10;
int x = 50, y = 50;
JTextArea typingArea;
Random rand = new Random();
public void paint(Graphics page){
        typingArea = new JTextArea();
        typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

        //Drawing borders w/ Random colors
        page.setColor(new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat()));
        page.drawRect(0,0,200,200);

        //delay
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        //Draws square          
        page.drawRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        x+=movex;
        y+=movey;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        Dimension d = getSize();
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        paint(page);
    }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println("Key is pressed");
    switch( keyCode ) { 
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            movex = 0;
            movey = 10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            movex = 0;
            movey = -10;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            movex = -10;
            movey = 0;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
            movex = 10;
            movey = 0;
            break;
     }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}}
```

Currently I am making a quick snake game as programming practice, as I am relatively new to Java, but not to programming. Using an Applet I am drawing a square and moving it over by incrementing x,y coordinates and then calling the paint method recursively. Did I use the wrong object(JTextArea) or is there a problem with my methods. Please answer quickly, Thank You.

Comment: The "main" reason you're `KeyListener` doesn't work is it's never actually registered with anything that is displayed on the screen, therefore, can never have keyboard focus.  You should never use a `KeyListener` with text components, it's just completely inappropriate.

Comment: I'd start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting works. I'd then drop the applet/AWT API and use either [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or JavaFX, you'll get better, general support.  I'd also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for some ideas about how you might generate a game loop

Comment: And you could just have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508913/snakegame-how-to-make-the-tail-follow-the-head/31509204#31509204) for some ideas.  If you're going to use Swing, I'd recommend having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and forget about `KeyListener`

Comment: Well that's a brilliant example of how painting shouldn't work in AWT.  Don't create new components in `paint`.  Don't call `Thread.sleep` or any other blocking/long running operations in `paint`, don't call `paint` again from within `paint`, you'll end up with a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can break this down a bit...

In you `paint` method, you create a new instance of `JTextArea` and add yourself as the `KeyListener`.

```
public void paint(Graphics page) {
    typingArea = new JTextArea();
    typingArea.addKeyListener(this);
```

Three problems here...

1. You really shouldn't be creating new components within a `paint` method.  The `paint` method will be called when ever you component needs to be repainted (and may be called often in quick succession) and `paint` should only paint the current state of the component, never change it
2. You really shouldn't be using a `KeyListener` with a text component
3. You never actually add the `JTextArea` to a displayed component, meaning it can never obtain keyboard focus and therefore never trigger `KeyEvent`s

Then you call...

```
    //delay
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    //...
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
```

in your `paint` method.  This is a really bad idea, painting should occur as fast as possible, as until the `paint` method exists, the contents of the `Graphics` context may not be painted to the screen

And finally, you call...

```
    paint(page);
}
```

This is a bad idea, as you will never actually exit the `paint` method once it's called (see the previous comment) and you will end up with a `StackOverflowException`.

AWT will call your `paint` method when it wants you to repaint the component.  You can request a update by calling `repaint`, but you should be aware that the painting will occur when the repaint manager decides something needs to be updated, so it may not occur immediately.

- I'd start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand how painting works.
- I'd then drop the applet/AWT API and use either [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) or JavaFX, you'll get better, general support.
- If you want to use Swing, I'd have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for some ideas about how you might generate a game loop
- If you're going to use Swing, I'd recommend having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and forget about `KeyListener`
- And you could just have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508913/snakegame-how-to-make-the-tail-follow-the-head/31509204#31509204) for some ideas.