# Java- How to link AWT Rectangles?

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I just started to write the game of snakes in java. (See this if you don't know what that is: http://codeincomplete.com/projects/snakes/ or http://elgoog.im/snake/). So, when the snake eats an object, its tail grows. In order for the turning physics of the game to work properly, each segment of the tail needs to have its own `java.awt.Rectangle` hitbox. My question is how can I link these hitboxes/segments of his tail so they always stay together, but are seperate components on my `JPanel`. Otherwise, if there is a better way to do this then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly have a "FruitManager" class that has an array/ArrayList of fruits, and controls when curtain fruits are placed and are visible.

Comment: @WyattLowery ok thanks, but thats not the problem, I need a way to link the segments of the snake's tail.

Comment: Make sure their edges are always lined up, for example, by always drawing them on a fixed grid. I would recommend implementing your own drawing method instead of using separate components for each block.

Comment: @MadPhysicist my own drawing method? Could you elaborate or provide an example? That would be great thanks!

Comment: The simplest solution would be to have a `List` of some kind.  A better solution would be to have a  model which describes the state in a virtual manner (separated from the UI), then the UI can render the current state of the model

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is deffinetly going to be sepearted from the graphics. I just didn't know any good class aside from Rectangle for storing data like this.

Comment: You could loop through your tail segments backwards, one by one, and set the coordinates of a given tail segment to the one before it. i.e. say you have a list of coordinates of the bounding boxes, and for simplicity's sake, only store the y values: `[5, 10, 15, 20]`. If you want the snake to move up, you would first set the `5` to `10`, then `10` to `15`, etc.

Comment: @frenchDolphin okay that could work, let me think about that for a bit.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Maybe something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508913/snakegame-how-to-make-the-tail-follow-the-head/31509204#31509204)

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay perfect thank you (again) ! I think that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There s should be a snake object, with a ordered set of simple snake piece, each piece showing type. Practice model view controller, each Snake piece should know nothing about graphics. When you at a segment, put by the last noon trail piece. So, your Snake would contain a list of pieces, like this:

```
List<SnakePieces> mPieces
```

SnakePieces should be simple, something like this

```
public class SnakePieces {
    public enum Type {Head,Body,Tail};
    public Type type;
}
```

Feel free to add other functions to SnakePieces as required. When you add a new piece, add it at the location

```
mSnakePieces.add(mSnakePieces.length()-1,newSnakePiece);
```

If you can, separate out the model (Snake movement), the view (Puts in the graphics for the piece depending on the type of SnakePiece), and the Controller (Feeds the inputs to the model). That's more advanced than required, but helpful. [See Wikipedia on Model View Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Also, see the [Android Snake Game](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/donut-release2/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake), which no doubt has some similarities to your application. Android does it via this:

```
/**
 * mSnakeTrail: a list of Coordinates that make up the snake's body
 * mAppleList: the secret location of the juicy apples the snake craves.
 */
private ArrayList<Coordinate> mSnakeTrail = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

It just knows to draw the first and last tiles slightly differently.

Comment: What are ordered sets? And what do you mean by "each piece showing type"

Comment: Added a bunch of stuff to hopefully make this easier.

Comment: yup thanks, makes a lot more sense! Also, I think this is what @MadProgrammer was saying.