# How Do I Paint My 2D Objects Within A Timer

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am trying to make the snake game using OOP. OOP is a new concept to me, as I typically use functional programming.

I have a timer and when it executes it should paint the snake and the food.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //SNAKE AND FOOD DO NOT SHOW UP HERE

            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            drawSnake(g, snek);
            drawFood(g, foodPack);  
            snek.changeYDir(10);
            snek.moveHeadY();
            System.out.println("Timer is running");
            System.out.println(snek.getHeadY());
            System.out.println(snek.getChunkX(0));

        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);



    //If code in timer is put here, snake and food show up


}
```

**A few clues I've deduced!

1. The timer is running
2. the head is moving - shown in the console
3. The snake body exists - shown to exist in the console

CONSOLE LOG:

```
Timer is running
340
130
```

Here is a link to the whole project.
https://files.fm/u/b8kvgebq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by having a read of [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to gain a better understanding of how painting in Swing actually works.

Next, have a read of [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understanding how threading works in Swing.

`paintComponent` should only paint the current state of the component, it should never perform any operation which may trigger a new paint pass.

Since `paintComponent` can be called at any time, for any number of reasons, many which you don't control, attempting to schedule a new `TimerTask` within it is a very, very, very bad idea.  You could end up with any number of timers attempting to make changes to the UI, which will degrade performance and potentially conflict with each other.

Because `Graphics` itself is also transient, you should never maintain a reference to it beyond the scope of the `paint` methods.

First, take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for better base solution.  You should create a single `Timer` which updates the state of the component and calls `repaint`, which will, indirectly, call your `paintComponent` at which time you paint the current state of component.

For example see [SnakeGame how to make the tail follow the head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508913/snakegame-how-to-make-the-tail-follow-the-head/31509204#31509204)